# Woocommerce API REST update product by SKU

Tags: php, woocommerce-rest-api

Hello I have this problem, I want to update a product from my store in woocommerce through SKU, I know that the product cannot be updated through the SKU, but I know that it must be through Product ID, the question is that I am using Insomnia to be able to do the product update tests, what I would like to know is how to obtain the SKU data from the URL that I am using to get the data, this is an example of the url

http://website.url/wp-json/wc/v3/products/?sku=ABC123&consumer_key=ck_xxxx&consumer_secret=cs_xxx

```
$products = $woocommerce->get('products/?sku='. $param_sku);
$sku = $product->sku;
$search_item = array_filter($items_origin, function($item) use($sku) {
    return $item['sku'] == $sku;
 });
 $search_item = reset($search_item);

 // Formamos el array a actualizar
 $item_data[] = [
     'id' => $product->id,
     'regular_price' => $search_item['price'],
     'stock_quantity' => $search_item['qty'],
 ];
```

I need help just to take the SKU value to search with the above cod and update product

Answer (score 0):

if it is about getting just the query parameter value from url, then try get_query_var function in WP.

```
 $sku = get_query_var('sku');
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/